# Error In SQL Server 2005 Express Remote Access in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Express by remote connection in C#. But when I search my ip on google I got my ip 10.130.56.79 and then I tried to connect with SQL Server it did not connect.

Then I find my ip by ipconfig command and I got my ip 192.168.48.152, then I tried to connect with SQL Server and now it connected .

But my problem is that why it not connected by a 10.130.56.79 .

Because if my client wants to access his office SQL Server from his home which IP will work?

please help me on it

thanks

Comment: Because your network need the right port to be openned, which is probably not the case.

Comment: @cubitouch but i tried 10.130.56.79:1433 it not working but when i tried 192.168.48.152:1433 it working

Comment: How do you know that this port is open to the public network ? (I mean network, private as public, not server)

Comment: i go at sql confrontation manager and then protocols then TCP/IP then property . hear i find the port no of sqlexpress

Comment: I guess that you may have a hardware firewall protecting your network (since private address work but not public). In that case, your server can be open, if the firewall is not, the request will never be transmetted.

Comment: @cubitouch please give me 4 reputation . i want to share a screen shot of my current pc conflagration . for that i need at least 10 reputation

Comment: What about hosting it ? (it seems to be a network issue, so I think you should ask this kind of informations to your admin system)

Comment: @cubitouch What dos min ? http://stackoverflow.com/ not allowing me to share the image bcos i have only 6 reputation

Comment: This kind of restrictions are in place in order to avoid pollution.

Comment: I didn't said your question was a pollution. But since you didn't got enought reputation points, that's why the system do not allow you to post image. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Sourabh Devpura, you can't access because probably you have a random IP that you need to use when you access the internet. When you use ipconfig, you have the IP of your computer.

Comment: but i want to connect my client office Sqlserver with my application from his home PC . please tell me how can i do it in c#

Comment: Well, you can see some examples of how to connect a remote SQL Server here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(VS.80).aspx

Comment: i already read this one but my problem is that hot to connect sqlexpress by 10.130.56.79 this IP address . it will only change if i reconnect my internet connection . but my internet connection was not disconnected during this process then why it not connecting . 

please tell me . is i have to need VPN to do this magic . ?

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL Server port before this IP? I mean, for example: 10.130.56.79:1433

Comment: yes i tried and also i tried it with both authentication modes ( windows and SQl authentication  )

Comment: Do you use a router? If yes, you need to open up ports on your router and open up ports in your firewall to connect remotely. Additionally, your SQL server may be bound to only on your localhost. You may need to look up the instructions to accept connections on all of your IP addresses for your server. You can see SQL Server instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277#method1

Comment: ya i did all this process . but i don't under stand about (  open up ports on your router  ) ? what is this ?

Comment: i am not satisfied yet and my problem sill remain but for your dedication i am giving you one UP thanks . and please help me to solve this problem . cos i am trying it from lest 2 days and did't got the right way

Comment: Well, if you actually use a router, you need to access your router configuration. It can vary according to the brands, so you need to access your router configuration and then select or create a port and let it enabled. This is a link that shows this process..but again, probably will not be exactly the same proccess because probably your router is different: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001201.htm

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'd need to open all required ports on your router so that there's even a way for outside connections to go through the router.

If you have a fixed IP address on the internet, that should be all you need to do.

If you have a dynamic IP address (which is probable if you use a normal dial-in connection), you should be able to configure a dynamic IP service like DynDNS or NOIP through your router that does the connection to the internet to give your network a "public name".

Then you can connect to your network through that name instead of the IP address.

That being said: It would be way more secure to use a VPN, as then the client trying to connect is considered to be part of your network and you wouldn't have to expose the SQL Server to the internet. However, you'd still have to set up a VPN, open the required ports and create a public name for your dynamic IP.